# Installing FASTCGI Mono for running ASP.NET on NGINX

Tags: installation, mono, nginx

I am a novice at Ubuntu and I've been given the task of installing and configuring NGINX to run ASP.NET applications. This is probably a stupid question but I'm using [this](http://www.newredo.com/2011/12/09/asp-net-mvc-on-ubuntu-with-nginx/) tutorial as a starting guide and I'm stuck with where I have to set a socket with this command:

```
fastcgi-mono-server4 /applications=/:/var/www/www.domain1.xyz/ /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000
```

What path am I supposed to replace `/var/www/www.domain1.xyz/` with? If I run the command as is I get this error:

```
Error creating the socket: Address already in use root@ubuntu:~# kill 9000;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Only one thing can bind onto a port at once. The error is simply saying there's something else running on port 9000. I personally have a few things that opt for 9000 so I would just change theport to something else (like 50333).

Or you could use a file-based UNIX socket, using the `/filename=/path/to/file` argument and then just connect your httpd to that instead of the TCP socket. That's a useful tactic if you have millions of servers you need to bind but not required when you only have one or two.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
fastcgi-mono-server4 /applications=/:/var/www/www.domain1.xyz/ /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:<any other port greater than 1024 and not equal to 9000>
```